# Java/Processing how to do Matrix Multipication with the dot product

Tags: java, matrix, processing, linear-algebra

Hello i am using processing (witch is essentially just Java) and I wanted to have a really simple matrix class to help me with my Neural-Network .

It works fine but the "matrix-multipication" part doesn't really work .

I know my code is wrong but i can't seem to find a fix .

The start of the class looks like this :

```
class Matrix {

   int rows;
   int cols;
   double[][] matrix;

   Matrix(int rows_ , int cols_ ) {
       rows = rows_;
       cols = cols_;

       // set size of matrix
       matrix = new double[rows][cols];

      // fill with 0s
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
         }
      }
   }
```

The part that is wrong is here :

```
Matrix Matrix_Multipication(Matrix b) {

    // Create new Matrix for the result
    Matrix c = new Matrix(b.cols,rows);

    // check if not number of cols is number of rows of b
    if (cols != b.rows) {
      return c;
    }
    // Compute
    for(int i=0; i< c.cols; i++){
      for(int j=0; j< c.rows; j++){
        for(int k=0; k< rows; k++){
          c.matrix[i][j] = c.matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][k] * b.matrix[k][j]; // here is the error
          }
        }
      }
     // return new matrix
     return c;
 }
```

The error is :

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcpetion : 1

I only get this error if the The column Size is one :

```
Matrix m1 = new Matrix(2,3);
Matrix m2 = new Matrix(3,1); // here the 1
Matrix m3 = m1.Matrix_Multipication(m2); // apply Matrix_Multipication
```

I think that maybe the constructor is also wrong but i don't know how it would be wrong .

Also you could show my a library for Matrices and how i can install them if you can't find any error .

ps : I did research , but I didn't relay find anything . 
I tried to write my own version of the Neural Network lib form "The-Coding-Train" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZAIkDcPkI&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Y7MdSCaIfsxc561QI0U0Tb&index=8 .

Please tell me what i need to improve on this question and this code .

Comment: Why not use an existing java linear algebra library. There are several: https://lessthanoptimal.github.io/Java-Matrix-Benchmark/

Comment: I want to understand how it works but i already tried "Jama" but i dont know how to install them  ...

Comment: Can you help me how to install Jama this libary ? for processing . it would be a valid answer for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You swaped rows an colums.

The first parameter in the constructor are the rows and the second the columns:

```
Matrix c = new Matrix(rows,b.cols);
```

And since the matrix is a row major order matrix, the control variable `i` has to run from `= 0` to `< c.rows` and the control variable `j` from `= 0` to `< c.cols`:

```
for(int i=0; i< c.rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< c.cols; j++){
        for(int k=0; k< rows; k++){
            c.matrix[i][j] = c.matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][k] * b.matrix[k][j]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah just discoverd that by my self i ate something and now i have the answer but still thanks maybe someone other has the same problem :D

Answer (score 0):

The first index means row. But you iterate till c.cols.
The second index is column. But you iterate till c.rows.
Just swap them.